# How can I get hold of a Google Calendar API?

Tags: api, calendar

I'm trying to integrate my Google Calendar with a plugin I installed on my page.

To do so I need the ID and the API of the calendar.

I managed to find the ID following Google's support page, but it's hours now that I've been trying to get hold of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this and more can be answered here: http://amazewebs.com ...the home to 1-to-1 google api help with lots of videos, guides, examples, templates and code submissions.

see demo: http://amazewebs.com/demo

To get a Google API you need to setup an API script to call the Google servers.
This can be achieved with OAuth Authentication with either:

- a Client Account or...
- a Service Account

Head to here to setup your API's & Auth:

https://code.google.com/apis/console

Head here for official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount